# as3 URLRequest sounds stored in array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, audio

I am trying to play random sounds from  an array. Here is the code I am using. Any ideas? this is not working.

```
 import flash.media.Sound;

//var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var mySoundsArray:Array = ["blue.mp3","green.mp3","red.mp3","yellow.mp3"];
var storedSounds:Array;

for(var i =0; i < mySoundsArray.length; i++)
{
/// DOES NOT WORK BELOW
storedSounds[i] = new Sound();
storedSounds[i].load(new URLRequest("sounds/" + mySoundsArray[i]));
}


/// later to loop through sounds but for now I use the line below default at 0
mySoundsArray[0].play();
```

Comment: `this is not working` any errors occur?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: pretty sure the issue is with this line - - 
storedSounds[i] = new Sound();

Comment: I don't believe I can have an array for a name. There may be a way to do it but that  is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `play` method to `mySoundsArray` elements since they are not sound objects but strings. Try changing last line in `storedSounds[0].play()`

**update**

this code worked fine for me

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class test extends Sprite
    {
        private var names:Array = new Array("blue.mp3","green.mp3","red.mp3","yellow.mp3");
        private var sounds:Array = new Array();

        public function test()
        {
            for(var i:uint = 0; i < this.names.length; i++)
            {
                sounds[i] = new Sound(new URLRequest("sounds/" + this.names[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the sounds to be stored in storedSounds?  - -   TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: storedSounds[0] does not have a value.

Comment: I would have done this: `var mySoundsArray:Array = new Array ("blue.mp3","green.mp3","red.mp3","yellow.mp3");`

Comment: You've forgotten creating new aray, so `storedSounds[0] does not have a value`

Comment: Still the same issue. storedSounds[0] does not have an array to play from.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau, man again you **DID NOT CREATE** `storedSounds` array. You need to add `storedSounds = new Array()` line. Edited my answer, btw.

Comment: You should understand the difference between **declaring** variable and **creating** variable. When you write `var a:Array` you declare a variable. When you write `a = new Array` you _create_ it.

Comment: Just remember the rule: declare variable -> create variable -> initialize (work with) variable. This is the only way to go. BTW upvote to my answer requested :D Need some rep-tion.